# Faux IOS iPhone GPS Location for Testing

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, gps

I am testing an app on iPhone that will update the app's info based on the user's location and speed of travel.

Is there anyway to faux or simulate this in IOS? I have done this in Android, but can't find a work around for IOS.

Comment: "Simulate location" from the Xcode debug menu

Comment: That's a static location in Xcode. I need to be able to simulate movement, as if I am driving in a car.

Comment: No, you can use a GPX file that contains a series of points